# Delay function until image has loaded jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have an image which loads on click of a button, this button is only available after the page has loaded. The purpose of this is to create seamless animations between 'pages' however, there is only one html file with hidden and visible elements displayed determined by click mouse click. Once the page has loaded is there anyway to check onclick of a button when an image which is currently hidden has loaded before completing the function. Failing this is there a way to load this image before clicking the button, in the background so when the button is clicked the image is ready to be displayed?

Comment: `$.load` https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: there is a library to detect when image has been loaded.https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/, I've written a blog on how to use it http://www.codereplace.com/post/2017/6/21/detect-when-images-have-been-loaded, might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code here.

Here the code is used a callback function. when the button clicks than the slide down after complete animation then load the image.

> **This is one of the sciences of lazy loading**

It's maybe help you

```js
$("#toggleButton").on('click',function(e){
  $(".mydiv").slideDown(1000,function(e){
    $('.myimg').each(function(e){
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('myimage')).css('background','none');
    })
  });
})
```

```css
.mydiv {
  display: none;
}
img[myimage] {
  display:block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 380px;
  background: #000 url(https://rentbluharbor.com/wp-content/uploads/ajax-loading-gif-4.gif) no-repeat   center center ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggleButton">Click To Animate</button>
<div class="mydiv">
  <img class="myimg" myimage="https://demo.sirv.com/chair.jpg?hue=10" />
</div>
```

**-- Thank you -- **